# React-Native returning view from AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to render card list from AsyncStorage. What i want to do is get all data from storage and create card list depending on this data. I can see storage data inside function but i cannot return view. Here's what i did.

```
import {View,AsyncStorage} from "react-native";
import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Text, Body, Icon, Fab } 
from "native-base";


export default class extends Component{

 async _retrieveData(){
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
    return value;
 };

 getAll(){
   this._retrieveData()
     .then(items =>{
       items.map(async (k) => {
         await AsyncStorage.getItem(k).then(ok => {

           var cards = [];

             cards.push(

               <Card key="">
                 <CardItem>
                   <Body>
                     <Text>
                       ok data
                     </Text>
                   </Body>
                 </CardItem>
               </Card>

             )
           return cards;

         });
       });

     })
     .catch(err =>{
       alert(err);
     });
   };


   render(){

       return(
         <Container>
           <Content padder>
           {this.getAll()}
           </Content>
         </Container>
       )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call getAll function inside render method because it needs promise to be resolved.

You can call the same function inside componenDidMount method, save cards to local state and then render that data inside render method.